# Можно ли скомпилировать js файл?

Tags: javascript, компиляция

Возможно ли скомпилировать js файл в машинный код? Если да, то как? И прошу, без всяких ко-ко-ко, js имеет динамическую типизацию, а не статическую. Бесит такое. Ведь можно научить компилятор переводить динамическую типизацию в статическую

Ещё было бы хорошо если бы на нём можно было бы компилить проги под efi хотя бы или под Linux. Мне не нужно браузерную прогу делать. А десктопную. Этот вопрос это не копия другово вопроса. Там ответ я не получил на вопрос про компиляцию. Надеюсь получить ответ здесь

Comment: Можно https://bellard.org/quickjs/

Comment: но в среднем абстрактный JS никому не нужен, а в реальности ты захочешь сеть, gui и т.п. и вот тут-то и огребёшь кучу проблем.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я чтото не вижу в вопросе про запуск js как приложения. ьуь больше похоже вопрос про webassembly. и не вижу компиляции в quickjs ....

Comment: Мне хочется сделать прогу под uefi. C слишком сложный для меня, как и c++. Я находил в сети библиотеку, но она уже не работает. Но достаточно вообще тупо чтобы можно было скомпилить под Linux это дело, чтобы весило мало и интрепритатора языка не было

Comment: @eri `Can compile Javascript sources to executables with no external dependency.`

Comment: " и интрепритатора языка не было" - попробуй go

Comment: @AlexeyTen на pyinstaller тоже такое написанно, но он не компилирует )

Comment: @eri Я слишком тупой для go. Я его не понимаю

Comment: @AlexeyTen а нет, вроде компилит, но в стиле cython  похоже =) тоесть типизация остается динамической и функции вызываются как яваскриптовские.

Comment: @eri ага https://pastebin.com/XgwgPkdh Это программа `console.log('Hello')`

Comment: У меня в голове не стыкуются желание писать под efi и «go слишком сложный».

Comment: @AlexeyTen это не уровень cython) всёже виртуальный код и 
eval('\x02\x04\x0econsole\x06log\nHello\x08a.js\x0e\x00\x06\x00\xa0\x01\x00\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x14\x01\xa2\x01\x00\x00\x008\xe1\x00\x00\x00B\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x04\xe3\x00\x00\x00$\x01\x00\xcd(\xc8\x03\x01\x00')

Comment: @eri о, я вижу `rt = JS_NewRuntime();`…

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/). С помощью него можно скомпилировать JavaScript в исполняемый файл.

P.S. Однако если Вы хотите создать десктоп-приложение, то я бы рекомендовал использовать ElectronJS. На нём можно разрабатывать под Windows, Linux и macOS.

Comment: enclose не компилит. И приоприетарная лицензия - такое себе. Electron js это вообще библиотека по сути. И он не может вообще скомпилить. Вы ещё напишите что electron позволяет писать проги под uefi shell

Comment: не обижайтесь, но вы пытаетесь использовать лопату для полёта. JavaScript совершенно НЕ подходит для ваших целей. Даже на Python это сделать проще

Comment: Всмысле проще? Python можно скомпилить только rpython и то только под винду

Comment: И да, проги на электроне весят пол гига.

Comment: Python является интерпретируемым языком программирования (т.е. программы на Python кроссплатформенные)

Comment: Да что вы говорите? Напишите прогу на пайтоне под uefi shell. Или напишите на нём прошивку для стиральной машины)

Comment: Так же глупо использовать для таких целей JavaScript.

Comment: То что Вы хотите сделать - это (относительно) сложно. У Вас НЕ получится сделать это на JavaScript. Самый простой способ из качественных - использовать Go. Сложный, но более результативный - использовать С/С++

Comment: Ну и зачем мне этот Go, я его не понимаю вообще

Comment: А Вы попробуйте найти хороший источник для изучения. На самом деле, когда Вы в него вникните, он станет очень простым

Comment: Например: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0zxh2TPN_I

Comment: Или https://metanit.com/go/tutorial/

Comment: Полностью согласен. JavaScript для этих целей совершенно НЕ подходит

Comment: @Linux_tester "Да что вы говорите? Напишите прогу на пайтоне под uefi shell. Или напишите на нём прошивку для стиральной машины)" - так вы и на js этого не сможете сделать. (забыл обращение по нику добавить, поэтому дублирую комментарий)